# SocketIoClientDotNet - Socket.IO Client Library sometimes emits two consecutive events and sometimes not

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, socket.io

I am using SocketIoClientDotNet - Socket.IO Client Library for .Net, and i am trying to Emit two events one after one. Sometimes it emits both the events and sometimes it emits only first one. Below is my code:

```
socketModel sm = new socketModel();
sm.CHANNEL = "channel_" + cHAT_MESSAGES.SENDER_ID + cHAT_MESSAGES.RECEIVER_ID;
sm.DATA = chatMessageModelObj;

string serializedData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sm);

var socket = IO.Socket(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["socketlink"].ToString());
socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
{
      socket.Emit("apimessage", serializedData);
});

socket.On("apimessage", (data) =>
{
     Console.WriteLine(data);
     socket.Disconnect();
});


 socketModel smSecond = new socketModel();
 smSecond.CHANNEL = "messagecount_" + userID;

 if (updateCount == null)
 {
       smSecond.DATA = 0;
 }
 else
 {
       smSecond.DATA = updateCount.Count();
 }

 string serializedDataSecond = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(smSecond);
 socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
 {
      socket.Emit("apimessage", serializedDataSecond);
 });

 socket.On("apimessage", (data) =>
 {
      Console.WriteLine(data);
      socket.Disconnect();
 });
```

When i restart my nodejs server, All the second events which were not emitted before are sent after restart. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should always connect and disconnect from the client, never disconnect at the server.  When you disconnect simultaneously from both the client and server random events can occur.

Comment: This is my API server which is emitting events to nodejs server. and this means I am handling the disconnect from the client.

Comment: Yes, but if the server is also issuing a disconnect after you start the disconnect you can have a race condition.  The only real way of telling is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and trace the TCP.  Look for the End messages along with the sequence number and see if multiple disconnect are being initiated from both client and server.

Comment: Why do you have 2 event handlers for `connect` event? It will be helpful if you put comments in your code and also explain why are you emitting 2 events back to back?

Comment: Two Emits in one event handler is not emitting both events. Secondly, I want to send multiple events not limiting to 2. Things different are channel name and data.

Comment: These events are coded in separate static functions. That's why I have to connect and disconnect socket each time.

Comment: You have 2 `socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT` in the same page, for the same socket. **AND** you have 2 `apimessage` event handlers again on the same socket, in the same page. I am sorry but I still don't get why are you duplicating event handlers..

Comment: I have two functions and each socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT and apimessage are used individually in each function.

Comment: So the whole code above is basically divided into 2 functions? and you merged them both while posting here?

Comment: Yes to minify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by Emitting both the events once `EVENT_CONNECT()` is successfully connected.

```
socketModel sm = new socketModel();
sm.CHANNEL = "channel_" + cHAT_MESSAGES.SENDER_ID + cHAT_MESSAGES.RECEIVER_ID;
sm.DATA = chatMessageModelObj;

string serializedData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sm);

socketModel smSecond = new socketModel();
smSecond.CHANNEL = "messagecount_" + cHAT_MESSAGES.RECEIVER_ID;

if (updateCount == null)
{
    smSecond.DATA = 0;

}
else
{
    smSecond.DATA = updateCount.Count();
}

string serializedDataSecond = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(smSecond);

var socket = IO.Socket(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["socketlink"].ToString());
socket.Once(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
{
    socket.Emit("apimessage", serializedData);
    socket.Emit("apimessage", serializedDataSecond);
});

socket.Once("apimessage", () =>
{
    socket.Disconnect();
});
```

Still, i have a question is there any delay in events.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar type of issue, this is because of the instance created for the socket object. First i used singleton pattern for getting the instance of the socket object which caused me problem, when i open the same application in two different browsers. So i gave a try of using session to keep my socket object instead of having multiple socket object. Try using session for the object instead of creating two different instances. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply. what do you mean from session?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain you can check here - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net . This will give you detailed explanation on session in asp.net

Comment: I know what session is, But what is session w.r.t socketio object?